# Google Reader is "de-syncing"

Tags: rss, google-reader

I've noticed that for the last couple of days any time I open or refresh the Google Reader app (the official one from Google) it marks the last 200+ items that are in my feed as Unread (which it then syncs out to my account! So viewing them online shows the same unread count), and seemingly refuses to sync out which articles I have read (though it does seem to sync starred articles correctly.) I've made sure that syncing is turned on, but this doesn't seem to affect it one way or another. Any idea's for how to fix this behavior? Anyone else seeing it too?

Beyond that, I'd be open to suggestions for an alternate reader app. My wishlist is for one that allows me to easily star an article from the list, only shows me unread articles unless otherwise requested (sorry, Pulse) and preferably has a widget that notifies me when there are unread items.

Comment: I've had the same problem, combined with some other buggy behavior.  Most frustrating is the fact that after reading an article and clicking back to the feed it will randomly tell me I have no items to display and I have to go out and back in to read them.  It's made the app pretty unusable so I just use the webapp which works pretty well, and haven't bother trying to find a solution.  Matthew Reads answer may help if you aren't experiencing the other bugs that I have.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the Google Reader app and service are no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the data and cache for the app (`Settings -> Applications -> Manage apllications`) and then syncing. Hopefully it will work after that.

Comment: As near as I can tell, this seems to have done the trick. Unfortunately though I also ended up getting an automatic update to the reader app at about the same time that I cleared the cache, so I can't say with 100% certainty that it was the cache clear.